# Deploy asp.net 2008 web page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a problem when I try to deploy a web in a client. The web has dependencies to other projects, the web and this other projects are generate locally before passing to the client. When I publish the web on the client tries to access the local path of the classes where they were generated the publication.

There any way to set up the publication to change this path?

[image]

In the picture you can see the path that generate

thanks!

Comment: Except the error isn't referring to the classes, it's referring to the connection string to your database server.  Be that as it may, you should have developed your application using relative paths anyway (where ~/ is the root of the project) that way it doesn't matter whether it's on your development box or the web server.  Also when you say "publish the web on the client tries to access" do you mean "publish the project on the web server, and then when the client tries to access..."?